# BookSleve Del redis key by wildcard

Tags: c#, redis, booksleeve

I saw this example on removing Key from redis usign wildcard

```
You can delete multiple keys with just one DEL command

DEL key1 key2 key3......


You can also delete all keys matching an expression this way

redis-cli KEYS "temp_cart:user*" | xargs redis-cli DEL
```

Let's say i have keys : key1a, key2b,key7a, .... and i would like to remove all that starts with key*

> **how do i tell booksleve to do that? when i pass string into its invalidate function with "keys*" it does not seem to do the trick.**

Comment: Booksleve can't do more than Redis itself can. The command redis-cli KEYS "temp_cart:user*" | xargs redis-cli DEL is not sent to Redis as it is. Actually the core of this is executed by the shell as follows: send KEYS "temp_cart:user*" to Redis, read results, loop through each result and execute redis-cli DEL. (I'm not strong in unix, but you should get the idea). I would try to investigate the EVAL command, but not sure as I have never used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis does not have a "delete by wildcard" operation. Note also that you should never use `KEYS` in production. At worst you should use `SCAN`. Fortunately, BookSleeve and SE.Redis automatically use `SCAN` when available. To do this, you would have to iterate (via `SCAN`) and issue multilple `DEL` commands. Which is, notably, exactly what `xargs` does in your example.

Comment: so if should not use KEYS _redisClient.Keys.Find(0,"key*") to search for wildcard key match, how can i use SCAN for that in booksleve do you have an example for above question?

Comment: @Justin as I stated: BookSleeve and StackExchange.Redis both automatically try to use `SCAN` when it is available; you should be ok using `Find`, but you might want to verify via `MONITOR` that it is using `SCAN` and not `KEYS`.